# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=\frac{n^a x^{n-3/2}}{1+x^n}$, $a\in R^+, x \in (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I have found the succession $f_n$ pointwise converges to the null function.
For the uniform convergence can I calculate $f'_n$ because $Sup_{x\in E}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=Sup_{x\in E}|f_n(x)|$?(E is the uniform convergence set)

Comment: Well, you an always try the derivative thing...but it is not going to be pretty.

Comment: Can I say $|f_n(x)|<n^a x^{n-3/2}$?

Comment: You can drop the absolute value. Everything's positive here...and I think you can say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that $f_n'$ is always greater than $0$. On the other hand, $\lim_{x\to1}f_n(x)=\frac{n^a}2$. Since $a>0$, you don't have $\lim_nn^a=0$ and therefore the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: can I have uniform convergence in subset of (0,1)?

Comment: @GiuliaB. Sure. The convergence is uniform on any interval $(0,c)$, with $0<c<1$.

Comment: If I want for which a is true :$lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) dx  =\int_{0}^{1}lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f_n(x) dx$ , the right limit is null. $\int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) dx<\int_{0}^{1} n^a x^{n-3/2}<...<\frac{2n^a}{2n-1}\rightarrow 0$ for $a<1$?